# Git Submodule has a wrong reference to its remote repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two submodules in my main repository, both linked to two another remote repositories.

- When I enter the 1st submodule I am getting a message "HEAD detached **at** xxxxxxxx" - which is fine, cause the remote repository and the submodule have the same ID (the 32 digits).
- When I enter the 2nd submodule I am getting a message "HEAD detached **from** yyyyyyyy" - which is **not** fine, cause the remote repository and the submodule do **not** have the same ID (the 32 digits). So, the 2nd submodule has a different ID than the repository it is linked to.

I think I somehow manage to put my 2nd submodule on some other branch or something like that.
Long story short, I cannot even clone the main rep anymore (`git clone --recursive-submodules`) cause the 2nd submodule has a wrong ID and cannot get linked to its remote rep.
I am getting "`error: no ref to the remote rep`".

Can someone help me?
How can I change the ID of a submodule?
Or do I need to get back my 2nd submodule on the main branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I change the ID of a submodule?

In your case, you cannot clone your submodule repo, because its **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, ([special entry in the index of the parent repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) references a SHA1 that was *not* pushed to the remote repo of said submodule.

Since you don't have the submodule folder content (it cannot be checked-out), you cannot simply add, push and commit from said submodule.

In order to complete the clone, it is best to change the associated gitlink SHA1 to its previous version:

```
git checkout $(git log -1 --format=format:%H yoursubmodule) -- yoursubmodule
```

Replace `yoursubmodule` by the name of the folder representing your submodule, without trailing slash (since it is an entry in the index, not a folder)

*Then* a `git submodule update --init` should be enough to initialize that submodule content.

Finally, see "[Git submodules: Specify a branch/tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)", and associate your submodule to a branch:

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
```

That way, next time, a git `submodule update --remote` will be enough to update your submodule to the latest remote SHA1 of that branch.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: what you got is, I think, the case I mention below where you have not pushed the *submodule* commit.  So now when the superproject goes to get the one specific commit out of the submodule the superproject has cloned, it (the superproject Git) cannot find it (the desired commit in the submodule).

#### Background

Submodules are a pain because there is an enormous tension between the fact that each submodule itself *is* a Git repository, and the fact that each "superproject" (controlling a submodule) *insists* that it *knows* **which** commit that the submodule **must** use.

This all works just fine when all of your submodules are external libraries that someone else maintains.  You write some code that needs libraries A, B, and C.  You test it with "commit `1234567`" from A, "commit `8888888`" from B, and "commit `fedcba9`" from C, and it all works ... so you decree that *this* version of the code shall *always and forever* use those three commits from those three submodules.

You do this simply by *making a commit in the superproject*.  Each commit records, for all time, exactly *which* commits the submodules *must* be on.

Then, whenever you check out the superproject, you tell your superproject Git to go meddle in each sub-repository and detach its HEAD.  This is *why* you see "detached at" or "detached from".  The "at" or "from" part is *totally irrelevant* at this point: pay no attention to it!  This is meant for your information when you are working *on* those libraries, and because you're actually working on the superproject, your superproject Git assumes that you are *not* working on them.

But there's the rub: what if you *want* to work on them?  Your superproject Git screams at you, *No no no, you may not touch them! I control them!* :-)  Well, it's not *quite* that bad, but ... it's bad.

To work in a repository, you generally want to be on a branch.  So you must go into the submodule and *undo* what your superproject Git did, by checking out some particular branch.  Now you can work on the submodule in the normal fashion.

But this upsets your superproject Git.  Moreover, you can't really *test* it until you have everything all lined up again.  You must enter all the submodules, yank them back into "branch-y" mode, work in them, maybe test them individually, and maybe even make commits.  Now you can go back to your superproject ... but you can't make commits there yet, because they're still remembering the *old* detached-HEAD hashes!

The only way to get everything all lined up again is to actually make the commits in the submodules.  Now each submodule has a *new* hash ID, which each submodule's Git assigned when you made the commits there.  You may now climb back up to your superproject and tell *that* Git: "I'm ready to commit, but before I do, here are your new hash IDs."  You do this by `git add`-ing each submodule again, which makes your superproject Git go and read out the submodule hashes and put them into your superproject's index.  *Now* you can `git commit` in the superproject, which permanently, forevermore, records the new commit as using the new hashes for each of the various submodules.

Note that if you now push the superproject, *everyone else* has a problem: the new commits you made in the submodules are in *your* submodule repositories, but those commits have not yet been pushed back to wherever they may go.  Anyone who fetches your new superproject commit gets a commit that says "submodule A shall use commit `feedcab`", but they can't *get* commit `feedcab` until you push *that* too.  So you must push all the submodules first, and only then push the superproject.

This does all work, but notice how brittle and fragile the process is.  Git's submodules have gotten better over time, in that you can now actually tell the superproject controlling Git to (recursively) descend into each submodule Git and put that *on a branch* (whose branch name is recorded in the superproject).  That takes care of the first problem.

If you're not the one who *controls* the submodule's remote repository, though, you get a different set of problems.  The `git submodule update` command has grown a whole raft of additional options to try to accommodate these cases as well.  The `git submodule foreach` command lets you run *anything* (such as your own scripts) in every submodule, which gives you complete control, at the expense of making you write, well, complete control.  But the situation with submodules is still fairly messy, and many organizations try to avoid them (I would, and do, myself).

Comment: There are few statements in your A I cant follow or agree with. But there are many descriptions here I like very much (as presented and done in form one cant find nowhere else). Thank you. Big vote up from me.